# Relationship Between Major Compaction & hbase.hregion.max.filesize

Tags: hbase

During a major compaction all the hfiles in a store-file are merged into a SINGLE hfile.

Now if the size of the hfile happens to be larger than hbase.hregion.max.filesize then the region is split.

So would this mean that one could potentially end up with a single hfile that is almost as large as the hbase.hregion.max.filesize?

I guess this is just a side-effect of the major-compaction algorithm, you get one monolithic hfile per store.

I guess this would be good for sequential access, how would it impact random access since everything is in one hfile, would that mean you'd end up using more memory to hold the hfile-index?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "side-effect". You can end up with a hfile which can exceed the max size. [Here](http://www.ngdata.com/visualizing-hbase-flushes-and-compactions/), you can understand the process of compaction. They managed to keep the file below the max size to keep the process simple